# TimerTask is not getting called

Tags: android, kotlin

In MainActivity.onCreate() I set up a timer:

```
    val t1 = fixedRateTimer("PingTask", true, initialDelay = 0, period = 10000) {
        val pt = PingTask(myDataset, myStatus, viewAdapter)
        println("Initializing timer...")
    }
```

The timer class looks like this:

```
class PingTask(val hosts: Array<String>, val hostStatus: Array<Int>, val adapter: MyAdapter): TimerTask() {

    override fun run() {

        println("Timer called...")
```

But it seems that it's never called, because there is no output...

Comment: It seems that you are not scheduling `Timer`. In java it usually done by `Timer()`. `objOfTimer.schedule(timerTask, InitialDelay, delay)`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change

```
        val pt = PingTask(myDataset, myStatus, viewAdapter)
```

to

```
        val pt = PingTask(myDataset, myStatus, viewAdapter).run()
```